# Title and navigation bar move when image is inserted

Tags: html

I am trying to make a web site for a church. Each page has a title at the top and a vertical menu down the left. The menu and the content should be centered and be 975 pixels wide. The problem is with images to the right of the menu, the title and the menu both move to the left. I've tried using absolute positioning for the image but that makes no difference.

Index page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>St Peter&#39;s Church, Marsh Baldon Refurbishment Project</title>
    <meta content="PageBreeze Free HTML Editor (http://www.pagebreeze.com)" name="GENERATOR" />
    <meta content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <style type="text/css">a.navwhite:link { text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; }
a.navwhite:visited { text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; }
a.navwhite:hover { text-decoration: underline; color: #ffffff; font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; }
a.navblack:link { text-decoration: none; color: #000000; font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; }
a.navblack:visited { text-decoration: none; color: #000000; font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; }
a.navblack:hover { text-decoration: underline; color: #000000; font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; }
a.titlelink:link { text-decoration: none; color: #004080; }

h1 { font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 30px; color: #004080;}
h2 { font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; color: #004080;}

body,p,b,i,em,dt,dd,dl,sl,caption,th,td,tr,u,blink,select,option,form,div,li { font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; }
        #mainDiv {
    width: 975px;

    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px
}
    </style>
</head>
<body><p>
<h1 align="center"><a class="titlelink" href="index.html">St Peter&#39;s Church, Marsh Baldon Refurbishment Project</a></h1></p>
<div id="mainDiv">
<div style="width: 150px; float: left">
    <table align="left" bgcolor="#8080c0" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" style="width: 150px">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#004080"><a class="navwhite" href="index.html">Home</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#004080"><a class="navwhite" href="our_community.html">Our community</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#004080"><a class="navwhite" href="plans.html">Plans</a></td>
                    </tr>
                            <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#004080"><a class="navwhite" href="fundraising_and_information.html">Fundraising and information</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#004080"><a class="navwhite" href="fundraising_so_far.html">Fundraising so far</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#004080"><a class="navwhite" href="statement_of_need.html">Statement of need</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#004080"><a class="navwhite" href="how_to_give.html">How to give</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#004080"><a class="navwhite" href="progress_so_far.html">Progress so far</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#004080"><a class="navwhite" href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#004080"><a class="navwhite" href="information_about_micklethwaite.html">Information about Micklethwaite</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#004080"><a class="navwhite" href="plans.html">Plans</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
            <div style="float: left; padding-left: 10">
                some text
            </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Fundraising and information page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>St Peter&#39;s Church, Marsh Baldon Refurbishment Project</title>
    <meta content="PageBreeze Free HTML Editor (http://www.pagebreeze.com)" name="GENERATOR" />
    <meta content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <style type="text/css">a.navwhite:link { text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; }
a.navwhite:visited { text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; }
a.navwhite:hover { text-decoration: underline; color: #ffffff; font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; }
a.navblack:link { text-decoration: none; color: #000000; font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; }
a.navblack:visited { text-decoration: none; color: #000000; font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; }
a.navblack:hover { text-decoration: underline; color: #000000; font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; }
a.titlelink:link { text-decoration: none; color: #004080; }

h1 { font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 30px; color: #004080;}
h2 { font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; color: #004080;}

body,p,b,i,em,dt,dd,dl,sl,caption,th,td,tr,u,blink,select,option,form,div,li { font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; }
        #mainDiv {
    width: 975px;

    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px
}
    </style>
</head>
<body><p>
<h1 align="center"><a class="titlelink" href="index.html">St Peter&#39;s Church, Marsh Baldon Refurbishment Project</a></h1></p>
<div id="mainDiv">
<div style="width: 150px; float: left">
    <table align="left" bgcolor="#8080c0" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" style="width: 150px">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#004080"><a class="navwhite" href="index.html">Home</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#004080"><a class="navwhite" href="our_community.html">Our community</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#004080"><a class="navwhite" href="plans.html">Plans</a></td>
                    </tr>
                            <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#004080"><a class="navwhite" href="fundraising_and_information.html">Fundraising and information</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#004080"><a class="navwhite" href="fundraising_so_far.html">Fundraising so far</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#004080"><a class="navwhite" href="statement_of_need.html">Statement of need</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#004080"><a class="navwhite" href="how_to_give.html">How to give</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#004080"><a class="navwhite" href="progress_so_far.html">Progress so far</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#004080"><a class="navwhite" href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#004080"><a class="navwhite" href="information_about_micklethwaite.html">Information about Micklethwaite</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#004080"><a class="navwhite" href="plans.html">Plans</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
            <div style="float: left; padding-left: 10">
        <img src="images/booklet page 1.jpg" width="785" height="1111" alt=""/><br>
        <img src="images/booklet page 2.jpg" width="785" height="1111" alt=""/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, but we require code in your question, not a link to a page (which, once you've fixed the problem, will confuse future readers who won't know what was wrong).  If possible, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I've added the html now

Comment: Your doctype is about 20 years old and does not apply to modern web pages. You are in "quirks mode" and it's like 1995 all over again. You are also using obsolete HTML attributes such as `align`.

Comment: If you're not willing to fix the poor page design, at least don't use `float:left` and set your page content area's width to `815px` (`975px` page width `- 150px` menu width `- 10px` content padding)

Answer (score 0):

In web is not adecuate to use pixels for creating websites , you can use percentages or viewport units check out this link for more information: [CSS Units](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

About the image **check out the order of the HTML elements** if the image is before it will appear before etc.

**Absolute positioning doesnt takes in count any element for the position**,that is used depending of the case.

Once you have checked that you can put images in your website from various ways, using an **img tag** or a d**iv with background**, in my opinion divs are more controllable , so you make a div and afterwards you add the next **css** to its class:

```
.myDiv{
  background-image: url("myurl/test.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 10vh;
  height: 10vh;
}
```

Now you can manipulate the position of the image by adding **margins**:

```
.myDiv{
margin-left: 10%;
margin-right: 10%;
margin-top: 10%;
}
```

After knowing where you want to put your image, you can think about using **media queries**, this are used for responsive design (In css):

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .facet_sidebar {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

That makes possible to assign diferent values or sizes etc. to items when screen size changes.You can find more info here:`https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries`

-As its seems you are not working from scratch , thus you're working with old code of the website and other person wrote it.
I would recommend you to make your own code and use a modern editor as well, like [Atom](https://atom.io/)

Comment: This is a tutorial and does not answer the question in any way.